# Duplicate polygons into new polygons based on values in columns

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, attribute-table

I have a polygon shapefile which has polygons that have single mill name attributed to it and also some polygons which have multiple names in other columns (Mill1, Mill2,Mill3).

[image]

What I would like to do is be able to split the polygon with multiple Mill name attributes into new polygons so that they are like the below.

[image]

I am struggling to figure out a way to do this easily in ArcGIS. I am also open to options of solving this using arcpy.

Comment: Have you looked at the split by attributes tool?  You could run it in a model or multiple times in batch mode for each field until you are done

Comment: Along the lines of Johns' suggestion... This [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/exporting-feature-class-into-multiple-feature-classes-based-on-field-values-usin/152165#152165) may help.

Comment: The only issue is that if the same name e.g M200 under the Mill1 field is duplicated 20 times, it won't get split into separate polygons if I choose that field. It only works if the names are unique under that specific field.

Comment: If you combine MIll1,Mill2,etc into a single column, you can adapt this arcpy code
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83210/splitting-strings-into-new-rows-retaining-geometry

Comment: you could use the field calculator and concatenate the `ID` field and `Mill` field to create unique names in a new field...something like `!Mill!+ str(!ID!)`